# Command history in interpreters in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, command, interpreter

Inside emacs I am running interpreters for several different languages (python, R, lisp, ...). When I run the interpreters through the terminal in most cases I can use the up arrow to see the last command or line of code that I entered. I no longer have this functionality when I am running the interpreters in emacs. How can I achieve this functionality?

1. How can I access the command history from the interpreter inside emacs?
2. Can I do this generally for language X?

At the moment I need to use python, so if anyone knows how to do this specifically with the python interpreter in emacs please let me know!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use <kbd>M-p</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-up</kbd> to get to the previous command. The complementary keys <kbd>M-n</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-down</kbd> will get you the next command in history.

Check out [Emacs' manual page on the shell history ring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Ring.html#Shell-Ring).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIS the keys are the same as in M-x shell. See menu In/Out for available keys/commands.